# Add words to languagetool suggesting list

Tags: java, spell-checking, languagetool

I use LanguageTool for some spellchecking and spell correction functionality in my application.

The LanguageTool [documentation](https://dev.languagetool.org/java-api) describes how to exclude words from spell checking (with call the `addIgnoreTokens(...)` method of the spell checking rule you're using).

How do you add some words (e.g., from a specific dictionary) to spell checking? That is, can LanguageTool fix words with misspellings and suggest words from my specific dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the API doesn't support this I think. Without the API, you can add words to `spelling.txt` to get them accepted and used as suggestions. With the API, you might need to extend MorfologikSpellerRule and change [this place of the code](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/master/languagetool-core/src/main/java/org/languagetool/rules/spelling/morfologik/MorfologikSpellerRule.java#L129). (Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of LanguageTool)

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I understand, if I'll add words to spelling.txt then it will cause add these words to suggesting list  on initialization only? 
And if I add words in running app, I need in extend MorfologikSpellerRule (and change code)?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is.

Comment: I have create one class and extend MorfologikSpellerRule but when i check in suggestion list, words not coming as per my external provided list.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirement, which is load some custom words into dictionary as "suggest words", not just "ignored words". And finally I extend MorfologikSpellerRule to do this:

- Create class MorfologikSpellerRuleEx extends from MorfologikSpellerRule, override the method "match()", and write my own "initSpeller()" for creating spellers.
- And then for the language tool, create this custom speller rule to replace existing one.

Code:

```
Language lang = new AmericanEnglish();
JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(lang);
langTool.disableRule("MORFOLOGIK_RULE_EN_US");

try {
    MorfologikSpellerRuleEx spellingRule = new MorfologikSpellerRuleEx(JLanguageTool.getMessageBundle(), lang);
    spellingRule.setSpellingFilePath(spellingFilePath);
        //spellingFilePath is the file has my own words + words from /hunspell/spelling_en-US.txt
    langTool.addRule(spellingRule);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The code of my custom MorfologikSpellerRuleEx:

```
public class MorfologikSpellerRuleEx extends MorfologikSpellerRule {

private String spellingFilePath = null;
private boolean ignoreTaggedWords = false;

public MorfologikSpellerRuleEx(ResourceBundle messages, Language language) throws IOException {
    super(messages, language);
}

@Override
public String getFileName() {
    return "/en/hunspell/en_US.dict";
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return "MORFOLOGIK_SPELLING_RULE_EX";
}

@Override
public void setIgnoreTaggedWords() {
    ignoreTaggedWords = true;
}

public String getSpellingFilePath() {
    return spellingFilePath;
}

public void setSpellingFilePath(String spellingFilePath) {
    this.spellingFilePath = spellingFilePath;
}

private void initSpellerEx(String binaryDict) throws IOException {
    String plainTextDict = null;
    if (JLanguageTool.getDataBroker().resourceExists(getSpellingFileName())) {
        plainTextDict = getSpellingFileName();
    }
    if (plainTextDict != null) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        if (this.spellingFilePath != null) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(this.spellingFilePath));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                br = null;
            }
        }

        if (br != null) {
            speller1 = new MorfologikMultiSpeller(binaryDict, br, plainTextDict, 1);
            speller2 = new MorfologikMultiSpeller(binaryDict, br, plainTextDict, 2);
            speller3 = new MorfologikMultiSpeller(binaryDict, br, plainTextDict, 3);

            br.close();
        }
        else {
            speller1 = new MorfologikMultiSpeller(binaryDict, plainTextDict, 1);
            speller2 = new MorfologikMultiSpeller(binaryDict, plainTextDict, 2);
            speller3 = new MorfologikMultiSpeller(binaryDict, plainTextDict, 3);
        }

        setConvertsCase(speller1.convertsCase());
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not find ignore spell file in path: " + getSpellingFileName());
    }
}

private boolean canBeIgnored(AnalyzedTokenReadings[] tokens, int idx, AnalyzedTokenReadings token)
        throws IOException {
    return token.isSentenceStart() || token.isImmunized() || token.isIgnoredBySpeller() || isUrl(token.getToken())
            || isEMail(token.getToken()) || (ignoreTaggedWords && token.isTagged()) || ignoreToken(tokens, idx);
}   

@Override
public RuleMatch[] match(AnalyzedSentence sentence) throws IOException {
    List<RuleMatch> ruleMatches = new ArrayList<>();
    AnalyzedTokenReadings[] tokens = getSentenceWithImmunization(sentence).getTokensWithoutWhitespace();
    // lazy init
    if (speller1 == null) {
        String binaryDict = null;
        if (JLanguageTool.getDataBroker().resourceExists(getFileName())) {
            binaryDict = getFileName();
        }
        if (binaryDict != null) {
            initSpellerEx(binaryDict);  //here's the change
        } else {
            // should not happen, as we only configure this rule (or rather its subclasses)
            // when we have the resources:
            return toRuleMatchArray(ruleMatches);
        }
    }
    int idx = -1;
    for (AnalyzedTokenReadings token : tokens) {
        idx++;
        if (canBeIgnored(tokens, idx, token)) {
            continue;
        }
        // if we use token.getToken() we'll get ignored characters inside and speller
        // will choke
        String word = token.getAnalyzedToken(0).getToken();
        if (tokenizingPattern() == null) {
            ruleMatches.addAll(getRuleMatches(word, token.getStartPos(), sentence));
        } else {
            int index = 0;
            Matcher m = tokenizingPattern().matcher(word);
            while (m.find()) {
                String match = word.subSequence(index, m.start()).toString();
                ruleMatches.addAll(getRuleMatches(match, token.getStartPos() + index, sentence));
                index = m.end();
            }
            if (index == 0) { // tokenizing char not found
                ruleMatches.addAll(getRuleMatches(word, token.getStartPos(), sentence));
            } else {
                ruleMatches.addAll(getRuleMatches(word.subSequence(index, word.length()).toString(),
                        token.getStartPos() + index, sentence));
            }
        }
    }
    return toRuleMatchArray(ruleMatches);
}
```

}